# Usercontrol UI doesn't change

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding

> UserControl

```
  <UserControl x:Class="NolowaFrontend.Views.MainViews.SearchView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NolowaFrontend.Views.MainViews"
             xmlns:diag="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
             xmlns:designTime="clr-namespace:NolowaFrontend.Views"
             mc:Ignorable="d" Name="_this"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="350" d:Background="White">   
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SearchedUsers.Count, diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" Foreground="Red" FontSize="20"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

> CodeBehind

```
public partial class SearchView : UserControl
{
    private readonly SearchVM _searchVM;

    public SearchView(User user)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _searchVM = new SearchVM(user); ;

        DataContext = _searchVM;
    }

    public void TimerSearch(string text)
    {
        _searchVM.TimerSearch(text);
    }
}
```

> ViewModel

```
public class SearchVM : ViewModelBase
{
    private readonly User _user;
    private readonly ISearchService _searchService;

    private ObservableCollection<SearchedUser> _searchedUsers = new ObservableCollection<SearchedUser>();

    public ObservableCollection<SearchedUser> SearchedUsers
    {
        get { return _searchedUsers; }
        set { _searchedUsers = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    public SearchVM(User user)
    {
        _user = user;
        _searchService = new SearchService();
    }

    public async void TimerSearch(string text)
    {
        var response = await _searchService.SearchUser(text);

        var data = response.ResponseData;

        SearchedUsers = data.ToObservableCollection(); 
    }
}
```

> bindig log

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): Found data context element: TextBlock (hash=56511253) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): Activate with root item SearchVM (hash=52539597)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506):   At level 0 - for SearchVM.SearchedUsers found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(SearchedUsers)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): Replace item at level 0 with SearchVM (hash=52539597), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(SearchedUsers)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): GetValue at level 0 from SearchVM (hash=52539597) using RuntimePropertyInfo(SearchedUsers): ObservableCollection`1 (hash=49313939 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506):   At level 1 - for ObservableCollection`1.Count found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Count)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): Replace item at level 1 with ObservableCollection`1 (hash=49313939 Count=0), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Count)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): GetValue at level 1 from ObservableCollection`1 (hash=49313939 Count=0) using RuntimePropertyInfo(Count): '0'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): TransferValue - got raw value '0'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 84 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): TransferValue - implicit converter produced '0'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): TransferValue - using final value '0'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=29516363) for Binding (hash=55475379) BindingExpression:Path=SearchedUsers.Count; DataItem=null; 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :  Path: 'SearchedUsers.Count'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.Text (hash=35990092)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): Found data context element: TextBlock (hash=35990092) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): DataContext is null
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): Found data context element: TextBlock (hash=35990092) (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): Activate with root item SearchVM (hash=64320678)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363):   At level 0 using cached accessor for SearchVM.SearchedUsers: RuntimePropertyInfo(SearchedUsers)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): Replace item at level 0 with SearchVM (hash=64320678), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(SearchedUsers)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): GetValue at level 0 from SearchVM (hash=64320678) using RuntimePropertyInfo(SearchedUsers): ObservableCollection`1 (hash=42592467 Count=0)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 107 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363):   At level 1 using cached accessor for ObservableCollection`1.Count: RuntimePropertyInfo(Count)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): Replace item at level 1 with ObservableCollection`1 (hash=42592467 Count=0), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Count)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): GetValue at level 1 from ObservableCollection`1 (hash=42592467 Count=0) using RuntimePropertyInfo(Count): '0'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): TransferValue - got raw value '0'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 84 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): TransferValue - implicit converter produced '0'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=29516363): TransferValue - using final value '0'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): Got PropertyChanged event from SearchVM (hash=52539597)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): GetValue at level 0 from SearchVM (hash=52539597) using RuntimePropertyInfo(SearchedUsers): ObservableCollection`1 (hash=53428882 Count=2)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 105 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506):   Item at level 1 has same type - reuse accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Count)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): Replace item at level 1 with ObservableCollection`1 (hash=53428882 Count=2), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(Count)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): GetValue at level 1 from ObservableCollection`1 (hash=53428882 Count=2) using RuntimePropertyInfo(Count): '2'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): TransferValue - got raw value '2'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 84 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): TransferValue - implicit converter produced '2'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=11842506): TransferValue - using final value '2'
```

Hi! When if there is a function that calls SearchView.TimerSearch("x")

I think UserControl shows the count that is returned from SearchView.TimerSearch("x")

But it's not work how I expect.

binding log says it changed to 2. but it shows '0' and never changed!

Can someone help me?

Comment: There's quite a few problems with your code (failed dependency injection, `async void` that then replaces a collection (!!) on a random thread, home brewed `Observable.Throttle`, uncalled `TimerSearch`, etc) that it's difficult to say what exactly your problem is. Try posting actual runnable code, but really most of your code can simply be replaced with correct `ReactiveUI` bindings that are known to actually work.

Comment: Oh and also don't replace your `UserControl`'s `DataContext`, that's the most anti-pattern thing you can do in WPF. `DataContext` is what links your control to your parent's correct VM field, including when it's repeatedly templated, like with `ItemsControl` or `ListBox`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding to the nested `Count` property of the collection. But since you are replacing the complete collection, the `Count` property effectively does not change as the collection instance change is not detected by the `Binding`. In other words, the `Binding` is listening for a `Count` changed event, but this event is never raised, because the collection instance itself has changed instead.
It's generally recommended to always use the same collection instance in a data binding context: clear the collection and add the new range of items.

Next is your async method `TimerSearch`: it is currently not awaited and does not return a `Task`!
Remember: `async void` is **only** allowed for event handlers. Otherwise, a `void` method must always be converted to return `Task`.

When you `await` a method you must `await` the complete call tree (all the callers too): `async Task` everywhere.

```
// Make method return Task
public async Task TimerSearchAsync(string text)
{
    var response = await _searchService.SearchUser(text);

    SearchedUsers.Clear();
    foreach (var data in response.ResponseData)
    {
       SearchedUsers.Add(data);
    }
}
```

In case `response.ResponseData` returns a `List<T>`, you can replace the `foreach` loop with a call of the `List<T>.ForEach` method to compact the code:

```
response.ResponseData.ForEach(SearchedUsers.Add);
```

Next, convert the calling method to return a `Task` too and `await` the `TimerSearch` method call:

```
// Declare method async and return a Task
public async Task TimerSearcAsynch(string text)
{
    await _searchVM.TimerSearchAsync(text);
}
```

Finally, avoid setting the `DataContext` in your control. This limits the usability of the control to be only used in the special context.

Generally, you don't have a view model class for each control, this is not how you design controls. Controls must be developed independent from a view model class.
In your case, the control would have a `UserCount` dependency property, which you later can bind to an external view model. Internally, the `TextBox` would bind to the `UserCount` dependency property.